# gdb on os x 10.9 cannot find object files

Tags: gdb, osx-mavericks

I've written a tiny test file:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello world\n");
    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

And tried to compile the program by

```
gcc -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0
```

But later gdb produced walls of warning similar like this

```
bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol bfd_mach_o_scan_read_symtab_symbol: symbol warning: Could not find object file "/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.1.72~6/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/_libc_funcptr.o" - no debug information available for "_libc_funcptr.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.1.72~6/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strlen.o" - no debug information available for "strlen.c".
warning: Could not find object file "/private/var/tmp/Libsyscall/Libsyscall-2422.1.72~6/Libsyscall.build/Libsyscall_dynamic.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/strcmp.o" - no debug information available for "strcmp.c".
...
```

Any idea to solve it?